# Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS can't restart/shutdown the system

Tags: server, 20.04, kernel, shutdown, restart

Recently I assembled a tiny server based on Gigabyte GA-IMB370TN and Intel core i3-t9100.
Then I installed Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS on it. By the time I write it I did `$ apt update; apt upgrade` and it has 5.8.0-44-generic kernel.
I am unable to reboot or shutdown the system neither with `$ reboot` / `$ halt` nor with `$ shutdown -r now` / `$ shutdown now`

Then I found the systemd shutdown/reboot debugging guide at https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/

It says:

> If shutdown (whether it be to reboot or power-off) of your system gets stuck, first test if the kernel itself is able to reboot or power-off the machine forcedly using one of these commands:
>
> ```
> reboot -f
> poweroff -f
> ```
>
> If either one of the commands does not work, it's more likely to be a kernel, not systemd bug.

So I did it and failed to reboot or shutdown. Sometimes it just gets stuck, or it may print some kernel trace message related to `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs`

When I installed Ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS with kernel 4.15 and everything works just fine.

Although I have seen many suggestions, neither `acpi=` nor `reboot=` kernel options have helped me to solve it.

What am I missing ? By now I'm not going to upgrade to 20.04 until the problem is solved.

Comment: Does your computer meet the min specs for 20.04? https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-system-requirements#:~:text=Virtualized%20Ubuntu%20Desktop%20Edition,-If%20you're&text=2%20GHz%20single%20core%20processor,GB%20of%20hard%20drive%20space

Comment: Yes it does. 3.6 GHz quad core, 16GB ram, 512 GB disk, usb and internet is available.

Comment: I would suggest a full clean re install.

Comment: I did a full clean install of 20.04 which had the problem I explained and then a full clean install of 18.04 with the old kernel that doesn't have the problem. I'm blaming the new kernel so maybe you or someone else knows the root of the problem. Actually I can live with 18.04, just curious why new kernel fails.

Comment: 21.04 is due out in April maybe 18.04 for now and try that later.

Comment: Voting to close: Since it works on kernel A and fails on kernel B, you seem to be describing a *regression* (bug). Try a 21.04 Live Server USB to see if the bug is fixed. If not, please report the bugt won't "be fixed" until somebody reports the bug and performs bisection to find the kernel commit that introduced the bug. Discussion of bugs should take place in the bug report instead of AskUbuntu.

Comment: @user535733, I'll try this and let you know. Thanks for the reference.